# Using array class to return array c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have this function:

```
array<int, 2> foo() { array<int, 2> = nums; return nums;}
```

This returns the error "array does not name a type". Why is this?

Comment: missing `std::` and `#include <array>` ?

Comment: Did you `#include <array>`?

Comment: `array<int, 2> = nums;` is also incorrect, you probably want `array<int, 2> nums = {42, 42};`

Comment: Why not `int nums[2]`?

Comment: @emsimpson92 because C style arrays are second class citizens

Comment: @emsimpson92 Part of the purpose of `std::array` is that you can use it as a return type without having to start typing backwards and sideways and diagonally

Comment: @emsimpson92 Oh yeah and because it doesn't work

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: You referring to this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossed_letter

Comment: I've just always written my arrays in the C style apparently. I've never seen the `array<type, size>` syntax before. I suppose it's pretty similar to vector syntax.

Comment: @emsimpson92 That's right. It's a useful C++11 feature (so quite old now!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The template is spelled `std::array`, not `array`, and requires you to `#include <array>` somewhere preceding that line

```
#include <array>

std::array<int, 2> foo() { return { 42, 42 }; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include [array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). And as was pointed out, you have the incorrect syntax for the array declaration.

Try this:

```
#include <array>

std::array<int, 2> foo() { 
  std::array<int, 2> nums; 
  return nums;
}

int main() {
  // use your function here
}
```

Comment: If you aren't actually going to initialize anything you can just have `return {};` in the function.

Comment: @NathanOliver Or just delete the function and leave `main` empty. Or just delete the program. Or turn off your computer... ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit But if I turn off the computer won't the internet get lonely? ;)

Comment: @NathanOliver It's okay we can just wake-on-LAN you if we get bored